# Erro Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015

Quando eu rodo uma aplicação, ou paro ela. Me deparo com este erro:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O que é isso, e como resolver ?

Answer (score 1):

Amigo este erro não aconteceu comigo, mas pesquisando na internet encontrei algo que pode te ajudar

Pelo jeito o arquivo **PerformanceDebuggerSwimLanesView.html** possa estar corrompido e ele fica na pasta **c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Platform\DiagnosticsHub\WebViews** então você deverá subscrever o arquivo por este [Arquivo no github](https://gist.github.com/tiesmaster/8d5187a800e1d5e2ecf0)

A resposta do **Ties** foi aceita pelo autor do tópico, verifique você mesmo.

[Link que encontrei apos pesquisa na internet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34070673/how-to-fix-internal-diagnostics-hub-exception-in-vs-2015-update-1)